# How to customize $ tagg before database tagg

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I already asked about how to put a `$` before a database tag, but now I want to 'customize that' so what I want is when i put:

```
<?php echo $m$userRow['username']; ?>
```

it outputs an error code

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$userRow' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\home.php on line 33.
```

But I want it to output `$mMohagames205 = (10000.00);`. So when *Mohagames205* logs in he sees that his Bal is *10000.00*. I hope you can help me out, thank you.

EDIT: I tried al the answers and it displays this `$mMohagames205` in place of the bal asigned to the username

Comment: `$m$userRow` what is this?

Comment: @Mohamed try my answer

Comment: https://eval.in/854505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curly braces

```
<?php echo ${"m" . $userRow['username']}; ?>
```

This will concat "m" and the value of `$userRow['username']` which will become the new variable `$mMohagames205` with value of:

```
10000.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $userRow['username'] = "name";
    echo '$m'.$userRow['username'];
?>
```

When there is a `$` sign surrounded by single quotes it wont be interpolated like when its surrounded with double quotes.

```
echo "{$userRow["username"]}" - Outputs "name".
echo '$userRow["username"]' - Outputs "$userRow["username"]".
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo:** https://eval.in/854505

```
 <?php 
     $userRow['username'] = 'Mohagames205';
     $NAME = $userRow['username'];
     $UserBal = '$m'.$NAME.'= 10000.00';
     echo $UserBal;
  ?>
```

> **Output:**  $mMohagames205 = 10000.00

Answer (score -1):

This one

```
<?php
  $username1 = $userRow['username']; // $username1 = "Mohagames205"
  $username2 = "m".$$username1; // $username2 = "mMohagames205"
  $$username1 = (10000.00); // $mMohagames205 = (10000.00);
?>
```

should work for you.